# Return a single relationship from multiple relationships between 2 nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and I have some trouble filtering out relationships in a return statement. I created two nodes and 3 instances of the same relationship between these two nodes that differ only in the value of the properties:

```
create (p:person {name:'batman'})
create (p:person {name:'superman'})

match (p1:person {name:'batman'}),(p2:person{name:'superman'}) create (p1)-  [h:HATES {intensity: 1}]->(p2)
match (p1:person {name:'batman'}),(p2:person{name:'superman'}) create (p1)-  [h:HATES {intensity: 2}]->(p2)
match (p1:person {name:'batman'}),(p2:person{name:'superman'}) create (p1)-  [h:HATES {intensity: 3}]->(p2)
```

When I try to visualise only one of those relationships (eg: intensity=2) with this code:

```
match (a: person)-[h:HATES]->(b: person) where h.intensity=2  return  a,h,b
```

all 3 relationships are plotted:

[image: all relationships]

Whereas by looking at the data only the filtered relationship is returned
"a" "h" "b"

```
{"name":"batman"}   {"intensity":2} {"name":"superman"}
```

Does anyone know how to plot only the corresponding relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the Neo4j browser. If you are using Neo4j 3.2 go to "Browser settings" and uncheck the option "Connect result nodes".

[image: Browser settings]

After it the result showld be:

[image: Result]

If you are using a older version of Neo4j you should toggle the option highlighted in the image below:

[image: Older versions]

Comment: I wasted so much time thinking there was something wrong with my Cypher and it was actually a hidden thing from the visualizer, argh!!